# KEDA and rabbimtq "NOT_FOUND - no queue 'nameofthequeue'

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, autoscaling, keda

I'm trying to make my spring app scale based on queue length (my app consume from rabbitmq and i have GET API that retunr the queue length so the configuration is right i guess) But after applying the keda file I got this error

```
  Warning  KEDAScalerFailed    2s (x2 over 12s)   keda-operator  error inspecting rabbitMQ: Exception (404) Reason: "NOT_FOUND - no queue 'projqueue' in vhost '/'"
```

meanwhile i can see the queue exist under after executing rabbitmqctl list_queues '/'

```
Timeout: 60.0 seconds ...
Listing queues for vhost / ...
name    messages
springBoot      0
projqueue       1
```

and I have the needed permissions

```
Listing permissions for user "guest" ...
vhost   configure       write   read
/       .*      .*      .*
```

this is my keda file

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: spring-consumer
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: spring-consumer-deployment
  triggers:
    - type: rabbitmq
      metadata:
        queueName: projqueue
        host: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local
        port: "5672"
        username: guest
        password: guest
        queueLength: "5"
  minReplicaCount: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 5
  pollingInterval: 10
  cooldownPeriod: 40
  advanced:
    horizontalPodAutoscalerConfig:
      behavior:
        scaleDown:
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
          policies:
            - type: Pods
              value: 1
              periodSeconds: 60
        scaleUp:
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
          policies:
            - type: Pods
              value: 2
              periodSeconds: 60
```

i can't see whats wrong in this how can i fix it and what i need to look for  thanks in advance :)